# Odd Intuitive proof for L'Hospital's rule

Tags: calculus

A professor of mine intuitively showed why L'Hospital's rule works for the $0/0$ case (by some simplifying assumptions). I understood that. He then contended that this is enough to prove that the rule works for the $\infty / \infty$ case. This ,he claimed, is because if the function for which we want the limit ($ =f(x)/g(x) $) is of the $\infty / \infty$ form , we can write it as $ (1/g(x)) \div (1/f(x)) $ and now the limit has both numerator and denominator approaching $0$. (this has also been argued [elsewhere](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hu0z-sFfF8Y) 11:35 onwards)  But I did not understand this last bit. I concede that both numerator and denominator behave so but the L'hopital rule we intuitively "proved" demanded that we should differentiate both the numerator and denominator *if* both approach zero. But differentiating both in this new form does not result in $f'(x) / g'(x)$ .

I understand this was not intended to be a rigorous proof, but this does not seem to work intuitively either. Have I missed something or is the proof odd ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, even the intuitive approach in this case will require some more work. We'll need the fact that $\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)'=-\frac{f'}{f^2}$. Now apply the $0/0$ rule to $\frac{1/g}{1/f}$ to get that the limit of $\frac{f}{g}$ is the same as that of $\frac{g'/g^2}{f'/f^2}=\frac{g'}{f'}\frac{f^2}{g^2}$ (if this exists):

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f}{g}=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{g'}{f'}\frac{f^2}{g^2}.$$

Now multiply both sides by $\frac{f'g}{g'f}$ to get the desired result.

But do keep in mind that we didn't take care of the subtleties, like why we can just multiply by stuff in the limit. But you wanted an intuitive proof, not a rigorous one, so there it is.

Comment: Yes but we wanted to show that the limit can be found as the the limit of $f'(x) / g'(x) $ at the end. Shouldn't we have multiplied with something else ?

Comment: @Sal_99, after multiplying both sides by $f'g/g'f$ (and absorbing into the limit), you get $\lim_{x \to x_0} f'/g' = \lim_{x \to x_0} f/g$. This says exactly what you wanted to show!

Comment: @izaak, Oh yes my bad . Messed up my multiplication

Answer (score 1):

$$L:=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\dfrac1{g(x)}}{\dfrac1{f(x)}}\to\frac{-\left(\dfrac{g'(x)}{g^2(x)}\right)}{-\left(\dfrac{f'(x)}{f^2(x)}\right)}=\frac{g'(x)}{f'(x)}\frac{f^2(x)}{g^2(x)}=\frac{L^2}L.$$

Comment: Yes but we wanted to show that the limit can be found as the the limit of $f'(x) / g'(x) $ at the end. I don't understand how this shows that.

Comment: @Sal_99: it is in front of your eyes.

Comment: Oh , is it in the last step? Since the squared ratio approaches $L^2$  , $g'(x)/ f'(x) $ must approach 1/L , so we get what we wanted with the reciprocal?

Comment: @Sal_99: you are reading the wrong way.

Comment: Please elaborate